# Is there a function in Python/Pandas to get business time Delta between two date times?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I've got a pandas dataframe with two datetime columns and I would like to calculate the timedelta between the columns in "business minutes".  It's easy to add business timedeltas using the offsets method, but I can't seem to find something built in that returns a timedelta in business days, hours, minutes, seconds.  I'm very new to Python so it's very likely I'm missing something.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: You can do this by subtraction. Check the [`datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way in numpy/pandas, but you can do it with python lib [`businesstime`](https://github.com/seatgeek/businesstime):

```
>>> datetime(2013, 12, 26, 5) - datetime(2013, 12, 23, 12)
datetime.timedelta(2, 61200)
>>> bt = businesstime.BusinessTime(holidays=businesstime.holidays.usa.USFederalHolidays())
>>> bt.businesstimedelta(datetime(2013, 12, 23, 12), datetime(2013, 12, 26, 5))
datetime.timedelta(1, 18000)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Although it seems that businesstime doesn't like negative timedeltas?  I also found businesstimedelta library, but haven't tried it out yet.